# How to group items from an unsorted sequence with custom logic?

Tags: scala, grouping

Having trouble with this... I'm not even sure where to start.

I have an unsorted list of objects:

`myList = (A, Z, T, J, D, L, W...)`

These objects have different types, but all share the same parent type.

Some of the objects "match" each other through custom business logic:

`A.matches(B) = True`

`A.matches(C) = False`

(Edit: Matching is commutative.  `X.matches(Y) = Y.matches(X)`)

I'm looking for a way in Scala to group those objects that match, so I end up with something like:

`myMatches = [ [A,B,C], [D,Z,X], [H], ...]`

Here's the catch -- **matching is not transitive**.

`A.matches(B) = True`

`B.matches(C) = True`

`A.matches(C) = False  <---- A and C can only be associated through their matches to B`

I still want `[A,B,C]` to be grouped even though `A` and `C` don't directly match.

Is there an easy way to group together all the things that match each other? Is there a name for this kind of problem so I can Google more about it?

Comment: This is an odd requirement. I think you need to construct a transitive function to replace `matches` (say, `matches2`) that encapsulates what makes these objects part of the same group, so that if `A matches2 B` and `B matches2 C`, then `A matches2 C` follows. Furthermore, anything in one group would have to fail matches with every other group, in order to be consistent. Even comparing elements to members of existing groups with your current `matches` will fail (`A` and `C` might end up in different groups if they are compared before `B` shows up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumptions, that

- matching is commutative, that is if A matches B, then B matches A
- if A matches B, B matches C and C matches D, all of them should be in the same group.

you just need to do a search ([DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)) through the graph of matches starting with every element, that is not yet in a group. The elements you find in one search form exactly one group.

Here is some example code:

```
import scala.collection.mutable

case class Element(name: Char) {
  def matches(other: Element): Boolean = {
    val a = name - 'A'
    val b = other.name - 'A'
    a * 2 == b || b * 2 == a
  }

  override def toString: String = s"$name (${name - 'A'})"
}

def matchingGroups(elements: Seq[Element]): Seq[Seq[Element]] = {
  val notInGroup: mutable.Set[Element] = elements.to[mutable.Set]

  val groups: mutable.ArrayBuilder[Seq[Element]] = mutable.ArrayBuilder.make()
  val currentGroup: mutable.ArrayBuilder[Element] = mutable.ArrayBuilder.make()

  def fillCurrentGroup(element: Element): Unit = {
    notInGroup -= element
    currentGroup += element
    for (candidate <- notInGroup) {
      if (element matches candidate) {
        fillCurrentGroup(candidate)
      }
    }
  }

  while (notInGroup.nonEmpty) {
    currentGroup.clear()
    fillCurrentGroup(notInGroup.head)
    groups += currentGroup.result()
  }

  groups.result()
}

matchingGroups('A' to 'Z' map Element) foreach println
```

This finds the following groups:

```
WrappedArray(M (12), G (6), D (3), Y (24))
WrappedArray(R (17))
WrappedArray(K (10), F (5), U (20))
WrappedArray(X (23))
WrappedArray(V (21))
WrappedArray(B (1), C (2), E (4), I (8), Q (16))
WrappedArray(H (7), O (14))
WrappedArray(L (11), W (22))
WrappedArray(N (13))
WrappedArray(J (9), S (18))
WrappedArray(A (0))
WrappedArray(Z (25))
WrappedArray(P (15))
WrappedArray(T (19))
```

If `matches` relationship is non-commutative, this problem is a bit more complex. In this case during a search you may run into several different groups, you've discovered during previous searches, and you'll have to merge these groups into one. It may be useful to represent the groups with the [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) for faster merging.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a functional solution based on Scala `Set`s. It assumes that the unsorted list of objects does not contain duplicates, and that they all inherit from some type `MatchT` that contains an appropriate `matches` method.

This solution first groups all objects into sets that contain directly matching objects. It then checks each set in turn and combines it with any other sets that have any elements in common (non-empty intersection).

```
def groupByMatch[T <: MatchT](elems: Set[T]): Set[Set[T]] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(sets: Set[Set[T]], res: Set[Set[T]]): Set[Set[T]] =
    sets.headOption match {
      case None =>
        res
      case Some(h) =>
        val (matches, noMatches) = res.partition(_.intersect(h).nonEmpty)
        val newMatches = h ++ matches.flatten

        loop(sets.tail, noMatches + newMatches)
    }

  val matchSets = objs.map(x => objs.filter(_.matches(x)) + x)

  loop(matchSets, Set.empty[Set[T]])
}
```

There are a number of inefficiencies here, so if performance is an issue then a non-functional version based on mutable `Map`s is likely to be faster.